# Airflow kills my tasks after 1 minute

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I have a very simple DAG with two tasks, like following:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': dt.datetime.today(),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
    'test DAG',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
)

t0 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task 1",
    python_callable=run_task_1,
    op_args=[arg_1, args_2, args_3],
    dag=dag,
    execution_timeout=dt.timedelta(minutes=60)
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task 2",
    python_callable=run_task_2,
    dag=dag,
    execution_timeout=dt.timedelta(minutes=60)
)

t1.set_upstream(t0)
```

However, when I run it, I see the following in the logs:

> [2017-10-17 16:18:35,519] {jobs.py:2083} INFO - Task exited with
>   return code -9

Without any other useful error logs. Anyone seen that before? Did I define my DAG wrongly? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Any luck with solving this issue?

Comment: Any luck? Getting this while querying a db then writing it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the task container doesn't have enough memory for a task, it will fail with error code -9. 
https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dag-best-practices/

Answer (score 1):

Which version of airflow are you using? 
 From 1.8, airflow is less forgiving scheduler on dynamic start_date, https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#less-forgiving-scheduler-on-dynamic-start_date.

Try to give a specific date.

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. I think that for some reason the scheduler thinks it's a zombie task and kills it.

Comment: @user1059968 how did you fix that?

Comment: I was having weird errors, Airlfow was killing zombie tasks wrongly ("WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to None. Terminating instance."). I had triggered the dag manually, running on "today's" instance (daily DAG). For some reason, it would kill the tasks this way after a few minutes, but if I trigger past instances it runs as it should.