# Airflow Task Fails

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, airflow

New to Airflow.

Airflow running using docker image with LocalExecutor, and execute a task that gets data from `MySQL` to `Google Cloud Storage` with below task. About 1 million records is expected to pull.

```
# Extract and Load customer table
extract_customer_table_from_mysql = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='InitialExtractCustomerToGCS',
    mysql_conn_id='iprocure_staging_db_conn',
    sql='SELECT * FROM iProcureMain.customer',
    bucket=bucket,
    filename='iprocure-bigquery-bucket/customer/{{ ts_nodash }}/iprocure-bigquery-bucket-customer.json',
    schema_filename='iprocure-bigquery-bucket/customer_schema.json',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='iprocure_gcs_conn',
    dag=dag)
```

After sometime it fails. Following is logs for this task execution

```
[2019-05-15 10:12:13,392] {{models.py:1595}} INFO - Executing <Task(MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator): InitialExtractCustomerToGCS> on 2019-05-15T09:05:58.731452+00:00
[2019-05-15 10:12:13,393] {{base_task_runner.py:118}} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run MySQLtoBQInitalLoad InitialExtractCustomerToGCS 2019-05-15T09:05:58.731452+00:00 --job_id 19 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/initial_load.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmp_f96d99z']
[2019-05-15 10:12:19,852] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 19: Subtask InitialExtractCustomerToGCS [2019-05-15 10:12:19,849] {{settings.py:174}} INFO - setting.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, pool_recycle=1800
[2019-05-15 10:12:22,540] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 19: Subtask InitialExtractCustomerToGCS [2019-05-15 10:12:22,538] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2019-05-15 10:12:27,379] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 19: Subtask InitialExtractCustomerToGCS [2019-05-15 10:12:27,365] {{models.py:271}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/initial_load.py
[2019-05-15 10:12:28,528] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 19: Subtask InitialExtractCustomerToGCS [2019-05-15 10:12:28,524] {{cli.py:484}} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: MySQLtoBQInitalLoad.InitialExtractCustomerToGCS 2019-05-15T09:05:58.731452+00:00 [running]> on host 3c7603479eef
[2019-05-15 10:12:28,728] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-05-15 10:12:28,718] {{base_hook.py:83}} INFO - Using connection to: datawarehousereplica.crgjkux43gqm.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
[2019-05-15 10:32:12,569] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-05-15 10:32:12,493] {{jobs.py:2627}} INFO - Task exited with return code -9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was a similar question: [Airflow kills my tasks after 1 minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794860/airflow-kills-my-tasks-after-1-minute)

It looks like Airflow is out of memory.